# MYSQL queries put some rows at the beginning of the results' array

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for the key word or the query to make some rows at the top of the fetch array.

Imagine I have some datas with some validation date. I want to order it by date with something like this.

```
Select * from items_table ORDER BY validation_date DESC
```

But, I want some datas where the validation_date is equal to 0000-00-00 to appear at the top of my results' array.

To resume I would like that the first rows would be the data with 0000-00-00 then the items ordered by validation_date. Something fancy like this.

```
[
[validation_date => 0000-00-00,id => 2],
[validation_date => 2020-06-04,id => 3],
[validation_date => 2005-03-04,id => 1]
 ]
```

I have some ideas to workarround as : 
 Do 2 queries, the first one to retrieve the data where date_validation = 0000-00-00, retrieve other items ordered by date excluding the results "where date_validation != 0000-00-00" and then merge the two arrays.(2 SQL queries and one merge function)

I can ordered my results at the client side but i think it's will consume some browser ressources for nothing. (1 sql query and one sort function)

I'm not convinced about those different ways.

I'm confident there is some way of doing it with only SQL query.

BTW it will be lit, if you have an answer regarding the Eloquent framework. But it will be already so nice to have an answer with the SQL query, I will not have any issue getting the equivalent with Eloquent FW.

Have a nice day.

**EDIT ELOQUENT SOLUTION AFTER ANWSER :**

You need in eloquent to disociate your "SQL case" and the order.

```
Item::select()->orderByRaw("CASE WHEN validation_date = '0000-00-00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC")->orderBy("validation_date","DESC")->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ordering using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM items_table
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN validation_date = '0000-00-00' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
    validation_date DESC;
```

This two-tiered sort first places all `0000-00-00` validation date records before records of all other dates.  Then, within those two groups, it does a second sort descending by validation date, to keep the original order you wanted among non `0000-00-00` records.

Comment: Thanks mate, exactly what i'm looking for. I need to learn more about SQL...